# How to dynamic programming with a LARGE input

Tags: dynamic-programming

Let's assume that we're now solving a typical problem which can be solved by dynamic programming - get the number of possible coin combinations for a change.

```
Memorizer mem = new Memorizer();
int[] coins = { 100000, 8534, 5935, 291, 76, 51, 30, 29, 7, 5 }
......

int getNum(int money, int idx) {
    if(idx == coins.length - 1) {
        if(money % coins[idx] == 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    int found = mem.find(money, idx);
    if(found != null)
        return found;

    int num = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= (money / coins[idx]); i++)
        num += getNum(money - i * coins[idx], idx + 1); 

    mem.remember(money, idx, num);

    return num;
}
```

But if the money is very large, something like 2,000,000,000, it's very hard to memorize all the intermediate results. How can I solve the problem with a very large input? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with this dp, it should be:

```
if(money % coins[idx] == 0)
    return money/coins[idx];
```

That being said, It is bad idea to loop on one coin value till you reach the money, rather, loop through all the values of coin. This way, num[x] = min(num[x-coin[i]]+1, num[x]).

In this code,  we could use memorization on part of array, i.e. last {maximum value of coin} elements, because, you only need to remember for x-coin[i]. Try figuring out how to implement this if it is what you are looking for.